# Java Question, how to get the value of a method from an unknown object

Tags: java, dynamic, methods

I have lots of object defined in the system, perhaps 1000 objects,
and some of them have this method:

```
public Date getDate();
```

Is there anyway I can do something like this:

```
Object o = getFromSomeWhere.....;

Method m = o.getMethod("getDate");
Date date = (Date) m.getValue();
```

Comment: Is there an interface that these objects are implementing to get the getDate() method?

Comment: If there is an interface, then simply withouth using reflection, you can use the instanceof operator before casting to that interface

Comment: there is no interface or the same parent class,
there is why i have to do reflection....

Comment: Because if there is no single type that defines the method and that you can cast all the objects into, reflection is the only way to get a handle to the method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you *can* make them all implement an interface, that would certainly be the best option. However, reflection will also work, and your code was nearly there:

```
Object o = getFromSomeWhere.....;
Method m = o.getClass().getMethod("getDate");
Date date = (Date) m.invoke(o);
```

(There's a bunch of exceptions you'll need to handle, admittedly...)

For a full example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Object o = new Test();
        Method m = o.getClass().getMethod("getDate");
        Date date = (Date) m.invoke(o);
        System.out.println(date);
    }

    public Date getDate()
    {
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tsk tsk, "throws Exception" is bad form.

Comment: @Henrik: For production code, I'd quite agree. But when writing a sample app to demonstrate a particular piece of code (really only three lines are relevant) I think it's fine. I mention in the post that there are a bunch of exceptions to handle. Would it really do any good to spell those out explicitly in the test app? Would cluttering up the program actually make anything clearer? Where's the benefit?

Comment: You are correct, indeed. I must've missed the mention of exceptions in my morning-haste, my apologies.

Comment: I kind of agree, unfortunately people do copy the style of the [example] code they have seen.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Object aDate = new Date();
Method aMethod = aDate.getClass().getMethod("getDate", (Class<Void>[]) null);
Object aResult = aMethod.invoke(aDate, (Void) null);
```

You should add try-catch to determine if there really is a method getDate before invoking.

Answer (score 2):

If there is an interface requiring a getDate() method you can check using the following code:

```
if (o instance of GetDateInterface){
    GetDateInterface foo = (GetDateInterface) o;
    Date d = foo.getDate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete the other answer(s), I'd also identify the classes with an interface. This is how I'd do it

```
import java.util.Date;

interface Dated {
  public Date getDate();
  public void setDate(Date date);
}

class FooObject implements Dated {
  private Date date;
  public void setDate(Date date) { this.date = date; }
  public Date getDate() { return date; }
  // other code...
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
  Object o = getRandomObject(); // implemented elsewhere
  if (o instanceof Dated) {
    Date date = ((Dated)o).getDate();
    doStuffWith(date);
  }
}
```

Comment: i cannot modify the other code...hmm..otherwise..i will do in this way then..

thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the extra dependency, BeanUtils can do this for you.