# Access Class Variable dynamically in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I have a scala class with various varibles like the one below:

```
class Square { 
 var x: Double = 0
 var y: Double = 0
 var width: Double = 0
 var height: Double = 0
 def area(): Double = width * height
}
```

I create a List of all the members of class in other file as:

```
val res26= List("x","y","height","width")
```

I want to access these varibles from other file as below:

```
val test= res26.map(t=>(t,s1.t)).toMap which throws below error:

error: value t is not a member of Square
val test= res26.map(t=>(t,s1.t)).toMap
```

Is there anyway I can access the variables dynamically?

Comment: what s1? can you put the full code snippet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala reflection to access all public fields at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465661/scala-reflection-to-access-all-public-fields-at-runtime)

Comment: To do what? Goal?

Comment: `val s1=new Square()`
Object of class Square

Answer (score 0):

You can use [java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/796338/432903) `instance.getClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName).invoke(instance)`,

```
object TestJavaReflection {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    case class Square(x: Double = 0, y: Double = 0, width: Double = 0, height: Double = 0) {
      def area(): Double = width * height
    }

    val myInstance = Square(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)

    val fields = List("x", "y", "height", "width")

    val data = fields.map(fieldName => fieldName -> myInstance.getClass.getDeclaredMethod(fieldName).invoke(myInstance))
                     .toMap

    println(data)
  }

}
```

Result you get back is :

```
Map(x -> 1.0, y -> 2.0, height -> 4.0, width -> 3.0)
```